# Raphael and changing the attr() of a set of elements (out of scope?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, raphael

I have created a `set()` of Raphaeljs elements called 'nav'. I am trying to change the `attr()` of said elements on `mousemove`, but for some reason the `set()` comes back with `Array length 0`...

There is a JSFiddle available here:
**http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/g8wHa/1/**

And this is a snippet of the loop and function:

```
function init() {
                sketch = Raphael(10, 10, 800, 600);
                nav = sketch.set();
                runNavigation();
                document.addEventListener('mousemove',checkMouse);
            };

            function runNavigation() {
                for (var a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
                    navButton = sketch.rect(navX + (a*105), 10, 100, 100, 32, 32).attr({
                        stroke:'#666',
                        fill:'#dedede'
                    }).click(function(){
                        alert(0);
                    });
                    nav.push = navButton;
                }
            };

            function checkMouse(e) {
                mX = e.pageX;
                mY = e.pageY;

                /* This section is broken... */
                /* It says the Array's length is 0 */
                console.log('x: '+mX);
                console.log('y: '+mY);
                console.log('Element: ');
                console.log(nav);
                nav.attr({
                    y:mX/2,
                    x:mY/2
                });
                /*****************************/
            };
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must've meant `nav.push(navButton)` in `runNavigation`